# Global platform lockCard() always return false

Tags: javacard

I made a test applet and install it with card lock priv.

Jcop plugin is returning like -

```
Card Manager AID   :  A000000151000000
Card Manager state :  INITIALIZED

    Application:  SELECTABLE (---L----) A0A1A2A3A4A5A6
```

i.e. application have card locking priv.

My applet code to lock the card is like:-

```
boolean check = GPSystem.lockCard();
                if(check == true)
                    ISOException.throwIt((short)0x6308);
                else
                    ISOException.throwIt((short)0x6309);
                break;
```

and this is always return 0x6309, I put this code inside Select file INS,

```
??>  /send 00a40000023f00
 => 00 A4 00 00 02 3F 00                               .....?.
 (55766 usec)
 <= 63 09                                              c.
Status: 0x6309
```

Any advice why this code is not locking the card??

=====update 1==============

```
Card Manager AID   :  A000000151000000
Card Manager state :  INITIALIZED

    Application:  SELECTABLE (---L----) A0A1A2A3A4A5A6  
??>  /select a000000151000000 
 => 00 A4 04 00 08 A0 00 00 01 51 00 00 00 00          .........Q....
 (73117 usec)
 <= 6F 10 84 08 A0 00 00 01 51 00 00 00 A5 04 9F 65    o.......Q......e
    01 FF 90 00                                        ....
Status: No Error
??>  /send 80f0400f07a0a1a2a3a4a5a6
 => 80 F0 40 0F 07 A0 A1 A2 A3 A4 A5 A6                ..@.........
 (18060 usec)
 <= 69 85                                              i.
Status: Conditions of use not satisfied
```

===========update 2=================

```
Card Manager AID   :  A000000151000000
Card Manager state :  INITIALIZED

    Application:  SELECTABLE (---L----) A0A1A2A3A4A5A6  
??>  /select a000000151000000 
 => 00 A4 04 00 08 A0 00 00 01 51 00 00 00 00          .........Q....
 (73117 usec)
 <= 6F 10 84 08 A0 00 00 01 51 00 00 00 A5 04 9F 65    o.......Q......e
    01 FF 90 00                                        ....
Status: No Error
??>  /send 80f0400f07a0a1a2a3a4a5a6
 => 80 F0 40 0F 07 A0 A1 A2 A3 A4 A5 A6                ..@.........
 (18060 usec)
 <= 69 85                                              i.
Status: Conditions of use not satisfied
??>  /select a000000151000000 
 => 00 A4 04 00 08 A0 00 00 01 51 00 00 00 00          .........Q....
 (67801 usec)
 <= 6F 10 84 08 A0 00 00 01 51 00 00 00 A5 04 9F 65    o.......Q......e
    01 FF 90 00                                        ....
Status: No Error
??>  init-update 255
 => 80 50 00 00 08 D1 DB C6 FD 59 68 54 C5 00          .P.......YhT..
 (176650 usec)
 <= 00 00 50 04 00 03 8B 5B 12 CE 01 02 00 04 E9 7A    ..P....[.......z
    E0 17 6D 62 E0 56 89 DE 7E 59 88 81 90 00          ..mb.V..~Y....
Status: No Error
??>  ext-auth plain
 => 84 82 00 00 10 CC D9 3C 88 3A E1 B6 A9 C1 B9 E8    .......<.:......
    2A 6B 90 FE 50                                     *k..P
 (148237 usec)
 <= 90 00                                              ..
Status: No Error
??>  /send 80f0400f07a0a1a2a3a4a5a6
 => 80 F0 40 0F 07 A0 A1 A2 A3 A4 A5 A6                ..@.........
 (33521 usec)
 <= 69 85                                              i.
Status: Conditions of use not satisfied
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may need to change your card life cycle states  from ***INITIALIZED*** to ***SECURED***. Then you can be able to lock your card successfully.

In *part 7.1.7 lockCard()* of *Mapping Guidelines of Existing GP v2.1.1 Implementation on v2.2.1 spec*, it shows that "If the current card Life Cycle State is not SECURED, return false."

[image]

Comment: it means from Process() with using code like - GPSystem.setCardContentState(GPSystem.CARD_SECURED); and then call the lock function will be enough to solve my purpose.

Comment: You should use SET STATUS command to change the card life cycle state.   Pls refer to this description of SET STATUS command from GlobalPlatform Card Specification 2.2.1
" 11.10 SET STATUS Command
11.10.1 Definition and Scope   
The SET STATUS command shall be used to modify the card Life Cycle State or the Application Life Cycle State. "

Comment: you mean before applet selection , Need to fire Set Status command like - 80 F0 40 0F Lc AID_of_App and implement lockCard() from process(). Is that you mean? Is card state and application state both are same thing?

Comment: Yes, you are right!   But  for the second question,  the card state is different from  application state. Here is state quoted from GlobalPlatform Card Specification 2.2.1, "5.1 Card Life Cycle   The Issuer Security Domain inherits the card Life Cycle State. "

Comment: I tried set status command with p1 = 40 and pass AID of application. Got 0x6985. Could you please see my edited post ==update1=

Comment: just read the line "For the Issuer Security Domain (card)," here card state means ISD state, do you think I need to use p1 = 80 and need to pass aid of ISD? see my update 1, use p1 =40 and pass AID of application and it gives 0x6985. Please advise here

Comment: please see my update 2, fired init_update and ext_auth command

Comment: You should establish secure channel firstly before sending the command.

Comment: secure channel means init_update and ext_auth? if yes i already fired. if no. please elaborate your words.

Comment: Please send command >> 80 F0 80 0F 00    to   change card life cycle state to SECURED.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116464/discussion-between-arjun-and-javacardos).